# How to use "double proxies" in (lib)cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

If I do this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,               'https://ifconfig.co/json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,         'cURL, used through PHP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,    true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,    false); // Only for the example.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,         CURLPROXY_SOCKS5_HOSTNAME);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,             'sketchy-proxy.ru:446');
$output_or_false = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output_or_false);
```

... then my computer connects via **sketchy-proxy.ru** to https://ifconfig.co/json , so that the webpage reports "**Russia**".

What if I want to connect to **sketchy-proxy.ru**, but then have that make another request to **loco-proxy.mx**, which *then* makes the request to https://ifconfig.co/json , so that it reports "**Mexico**" instead of "Russia"?

Is this possible? If so, how? I cannot understand what I'd do to cause such a "two-hop" connection to be made.

*Note: I don't control any of these proxies, so I can't install any special software or anything like that. I just get them with the VPN account, and I've always wondered about this concept.*

I've heard people claim many times that it's possible, but they are unwilling to explain how, simply telling me that "proxies aren't secure anyway so you shouldn't be doing it". I don't care if they aren't secure. I don't even have a practical application for this. I just want to do it once and then probably never do it again, just to have seen it. I don't even have a guess as to what possible code in my PHP script could cause this to happen. I frankly don't believe that it's possible.

Comment: _“What if I want to connect to sketchy-proxy.ru, but then have that make another request to loco-proxy.mx”_ - then someone in control of `sketchy-proxy.ru` would have to set this up. _You_ can of course not control how a system that is not under your control to begin with makes connections to any other websites.

Comment: So you're saying that it's not possible unless I control the proxy servers and can do custom rules?

Comment: Unless that proxy was offering any kind of special request syntax or API for such purposes - no.